# Unable to start nginx on docker with mounted volume

Tags: nginx, docker, containers

I'm trying to create a container with a mounted volume so that nginx can use my custom config files. However, the container doesn't start up.

```
docker-1.6.0 run --name a2 -p 443:443 -v /etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d -P -d nginx
```

I see no containers running when I execute a

```
docker-1.6.0 ps
```

However,
running a

```
docker-1.6.0 run --name a1 -p 443:443 -P -d nginx
```

shows the default page perfectly.

Am I using the commands correctly? Are there any dependencies when I use the first command.

I've referred to https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-nginx-plus-docker/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Are your nginx config files present in both the host and the container at the location /etc/nginx/conf.d?

Is it the container itself that doesn't startup or just nginx?

Comment: I'm not adding a new Dockerfile. I need the files under /etc/nginx/conf.d to be mounted into the same directory path inside the container. However, the container doesn't start up at all.

Comment: I've tried this out myself and I can replicate the problem if I put a syntax error in the nginx config file on the host machine. Can you post your nginx config?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, a strong possibility is a syntax error in the nginx config files on the host.

If you copy the default nginx config file to the host, the commands above run fine, but if you introduce a syntax error into the config file on the host, then the container will not run.